# Styling different icon positions in boxes with Sass

Tags: html, css, sass

I've been learning Sass recently and I've made a small project to master key concepts. I've tried to use placeholder to make different styles of boxes. I have a few questions:

- is the project generally correct (metodology, semantics, sass
  structure)?
- is it right to use nested style in placeholder (.icon in %feature-box
  in my case)? If not, how can I address this problem?
- for .feature-box-icon-right and .feature-box-icon-left i've made new
  block formatting context by adding 'overflow: hidden' to paragraph in
  order to leave space under icon blank but I've repeated the line in
  declarations; how can I make it better?

Here's [a pen](http://codepen.io/kr099/pen/vKwVRr).

**Here's the HTML for one section:**

```
<section id="icons-left">
  <h2>Icons on the left</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="feature-box-icon-left">
      <i class="icon ion-flag"></i>
      <h3 class="title">Some title</h3>
      <!-- /.title -->
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel tincidunt erat. Curabitur elementum nulla eget est ornare venenatis. Sed id turpis ex. Pellentesque massa nunc. </p>
      <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.feature-box -->
    <div class="feature-box-icon-left">
      <i class="icon ion-compose"></i>
      <h3 class="title">Some title</h3>
      <!-- /.title -->
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel tincidunt erat. Curabitur elementum nulla eget est ornare venenatis. Sed id turpis ex. Pellentesque massa nunc. </p>
      <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.feature-box -->
    <div class="feature-box-icon-left">
      <i class="icon ion-refresh"></i>
      <h3 class="title">Some title</h3>
      <!-- /.title -->
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel tincidunt erat. Curabitur elementum nulla eget est ornare venenatis. Sed id turpis ex. Pellentesque massa nunc. </p>
      <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.feature-box -->
    <div class="feature-box-icon-left">
      <i class="icon ion-checkmark"></i>
      <h3 class="title">Some title</h3>
      <!-- /.title -->
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel tincidunt erat. Curabitur elementum nulla eget est ornare venenatis. Sed id turpis ex. Pellentesque massa nunc. </p>
      <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.feature-box -->
    <div class="feature-box-icon-left">
      <i class="icon ion-search"></i>
      <h3 class="title">Some title</h3>
      <!-- /.title -->
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel tincidunt erat. Curabitur elementum nulla eget est ornare venenatis. Sed id turpis ex. Pellentesque massa nunc. </p>
      <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.feature-box -->
    <div class="feature-box-icon-left">
      <i class="icon ion-paper-airplane"></i>
      <h3 class="title">Some title</h3>
      <!-- /.title -->
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel tincidunt erat. Curabitur elementum nulla eget est ornare venenatis. Sed id turpis ex. Pellentesque massa nunc. </p>
      <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.feature-box -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</section>
<!-- /#icons-left -->
```

**Sass**

```
@import 'compass';
@import 'compass/reset';
$bg-color: #efefef;
$color-primary: #090;
$color-secondary: #333;
$container-width: 960px;
$feature-box-width: 33.333%;
$feature-box-gutter: 15px;
$icon-font-size: 50px;
$icon-margin: 15px;

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: $bg-color;
  font: {
    family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    size: 14px;
    weight: 300;
  }
  line-height: 20px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 7px 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: $color-primary;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

section {
  padding: 30px 0;
  h2 {
    text-align: center;
    background: darken($bg-color, 10%);
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
}

.container {
  max-width: $container-width;
  margin: 0 auto;
  @include clearfix;
}

%feature-box {
  width: $feature-box-width;
  padding: $feature-box-gutter;
  float: left;
  .icon {
    font-size: $icon-font-size;
    color: $color-primary;
  }
  &.offset {
    margin-left: $feature-box-width;
  }
}

.feature-box-icon-left {
  @extend %feature-box;
  .icon {
    float: left;
    margin-right: $icon-margin;
  }
  .title,
  .content {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
.feature-box-icon-right {
  @extend %feature-box;
  .icon {
    float: right;
    margin-left: $icon-margin;
  }
  .title,
  .content {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
.feature-box-icon-top {
  @extend %feature-box;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**Complied CSS**

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

html {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

caption, th, td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

q, blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

a img {
  border: none;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
  display: block;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #efefef;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 20px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 7px 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #090;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

section {
  padding: 30px 0;
}
section h2 {
  text-align: center;
  background: #d6d6d6;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.feature-box-icon-left, .feature-box-icon-right, .feature-box-icon-top {
  width: 33.333%;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
}
.feature-box-icon-left .icon, .feature-box-icon-right .icon, .feature-box-icon-top .icon {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #090;
}
.offset.feature-box-icon-left, .offset.feature-box-icon-right, .offset.feature-box-icon-top {
  margin-left: 33.333%;
}

.feature-box-icon-left .icon {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.feature-box-icon-left .title,
.feature-box-icon-left .content {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.feature-box-icon-right .icon {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.feature-box-icon-right .title,
.feature-box-icon-right .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
}

.feature-box-icon-top {
  text-align: center;
}
```